# How do I scrape a website that changes the order of its media file after each refresh?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape the media files of a specific website that has notes in it. I tried many times to download the notes from it and it was really easy to get the files but none of them were in order. The website is likely to make an Ajax call after you scroll to page 30 and then next 30 pages load up and it goes on like this until the end of pages. Can someone please give me a direction how to get the files in the correct order ? I know the question isn't sufficient enough but I just want a general idea about how to solve this issue.

> I am dropping the website for reference
> https://lecturenotes.in/m/37320-note-for-java-programming-java-by-prateek-jain?reading=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the website is making an intial request to `https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-1?noOfItems=30` to load the first page with 30 items. When the 30th slide is reached through scrolling, another request is being made to `https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-30?noOfItems=10` which loads 10 items then you've a request to `https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-39?noOfItems=10` and so on and so forth.

So your approach would be to keep a count of the elements (pages) loaded an increase it by an offset. Such as:

```
import requests # This proof of concept requires the requests module

slides = []
lecture_id = "37320" # The ID of the lecture
itemsToLoad = 10 # Pages to load per request
page = 1 # Page number

while page < 70:
    data = requests.get(f"https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/{lecture_id}/page-{page}?noOfItems={itemsToLoad}").json()

    pages = data.get('page', [])
    if not pages: break

    slides.extend(pages)
    page += len(pages) - 1

print(slides) # [{'id': '5d83d172662e4e36315ce88a', 'path': '/uploads/upload/5d83/5d83d1/5d83d15f662e4e36315ce885/ck0r2ehe96f3c0qqu1y5z7gi8.jpg', 'width': 1000, 'height': 562, 'text': 'JAVA\n\n', 'upgradeToPrime': False, 'type': 'jpg', 'pageNum': 1}, {'id': '5d83d172662e4e36315ce88b', 'path': '/uploads/upload/5d83/5d83d1/5d83d15f662e4e36315ce885/ck0r2ehec6f3d0qqufouvgf96.jpg', 'width': 1000, 'height': 562, 'text': 'JAVA FROM\nC++\n\n', 'upgradeToPrime': False, 'type': 'jpg', 'pageNum': 2} ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I am really new to scraping and I thought it's really really hard but thank you so much for showing me some hope . God bless you my friend.

Comment: You're welcome. Everyone has to start somewhere at some point. If this answer has solved your problem, make sure to accept it and don't hesitate to upvote.

Comment: Can I ask you something if you don't mind ? I am kinda newbie, so please don't mind

Comment: Certainly. I am all ears.

Comment: Alright then, when you first saw that website, the one I provided in my question. What was your first thought ? I mean how did you come up with the idea of scraping it ? I have no instructors. I just see videos and learn that's why I lack the foundation. So please don't mind me

Comment: Open up the Network tab on your browser. Mostly the content that's loaded dynamically you'll have ajax requests involved so filter out ajax requests by clicking the 'XHR' filter then fiddle around with the webpage to load new content and see the request(s) being made. From there you can have an overall idea of how to fetch things. You can also see the different headers, parameters and response from this tool. Then you can replicate this behaviour using Python. I suggest you look more into this tool as it has many cool features. If this doesn't cut it you need to dig into the Javascript code.

Comment: Wow, I did what you said and man it is there id by id. I can see those direct links. Thanks again. Thanks a lot Sensei . God bless you,  good man

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question but these are information for you to scrape:

After I open Network tab of Dev tool and reload the page, I found:

- Details about the lecture at: https://lecturenotes.in/material/v1/37320/details
- Info about pages: [https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-[i]](https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-%5Bi%5D)

Scrape the page in R:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
details <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://lecturenotes.in/material/v1/37320/details")
lecture <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    1:details$material$pagesCount,
    function(i) {
      as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://lecturenotes.in/material/v2/37320/page-", i))$page)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    path = paste0("https://lecturenotes.in", path)
  )
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much . It helped me a lot. Please upvote the question.